# Alternative to using sessions without having to make too many database requests?

Tags: laravel, api, session

I have a quiz app that has a Vue frontend and Laravel backend.

Assume I have a table called **Questions** with 1000+ questions (rows). Each question belongs to many (or just one) **Modules** (another table).

User picks a module they want to be quizzed on. The default number of questions in a quiz is 30. These questions are presented in a random order from the database - one at a time, and are not repeated until user has eventually seen all questions for that module in the database.

What would be the best way of doing this?

---

Currently this is what I’m doing:

Vue (frontend) monitors the question count (default is 30) - when this count is reached - quiz ends and score is presented.

User selects {module} they want to be quizzed on.

Vue makes axios GET request to /random/all/{module}.

This route calls the ModuleController@random method which will return a single random question (that the user has not seen before) for that module.

```
public function random(Module $module, $name){
    // Get all questions for module. 

    $questions = $module->questions->shuffle()->pluck('id');

    // Get unseenQuestions

    $sessionName = 'unseenQuestions_' . $name .  strval($module->id); //unseenQuestions_all_2

    if (session()->has($sessionName)) {
        $unseenQuestions = session()->get($sessionName);

    } else {
        $unseenQuestions = collect($questions);

    }

    // Pop new Question

    $newQuestionID = $unseenQuestions->shift();;

    // Store unseenQuestions OR remove unseenQuestions (if it has no items)

    if ($unseenQuestions->count() == 0) {
        session()->forget($sessionName);
    } else {
        session()->put($sessionName, $unseenQuestions);
    }

    return new QuestionResource(Question::find($newQuestionID));
}
```

As you can tell, this utilises sessions to be able to remember what questions a user has and has not seen already. I was wondering if there is a better way around this. I would ideally like to have some API end point that allows me to do this, but I know that API are stateless and so using sessions won’t work.

Comment: For more clarity, what is the issue with database calls within your application?

Comment: Sorry, there are no issues with database calls. I just want to know if there are any possible solutions without me having to store the unseenQuestions in a database as opposed to a session variable.

Comment: Wouldnt be a bad thing. If the users session expires, they would need to complete the quiz again. However if stored in the DB, they could start where they left off.

Comment: You are using Vue so if your quiz questions are not many (30 as you mentioned) then you can retrieve all questions and send them to the user where they are revealed one at a time on the client-side. That shouldn't be too straining. You could also save the question identifiers for the current quiz in the session along with additional metadata to retrieve them again if the connection is lost but generally that should not happen that often. Could have small AJAX calls to the serverside to update the current quiz state.